# List shifted right

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I can't seem to figure out how to get my list of links to be fully centered. It seems shifted to the right to me. Sorry for the very simple question, I'm new to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/mzm7szqn/

```
        ul{
            text-align:center;
            width:450px;
            margin:0 auto;
            font-family:arial;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        li{
            font-family:osr;
            display:inline;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

`<ul>
<li><a href = "#">Web Page</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">After Effects</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Premiere</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Ableton Live</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Blender</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Auto CAD</a></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `<ul>` has a padding of `20px;` that it inherited.  Try adding this

```
ul{padding: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add padding: 0; to the ul style.  so it would be:

```
        ul{
            text-align:center;
            width:450px;
            margin:0 auto;
            font-family:arial;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
```